# embedding torus

Tags: riemannian-geometry

could anyone please help me?
why is it impossible to embed a torus in R^3 with index 1 ( usual euclidean space with index 1 as a semi-riemannian manifold) as a semi-riemannian submanifold?

---

thanx.
but i didn't understand.
let me ask another question.
why with this metric R^3 doesn't have any compact semi-riemannian submanifold?

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that by "usual" you mean $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the semi-Riemannian metric $dx^2 + dy^2 - dz^2$?

If so, for any compact surface $S$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, since the metric is invariant under translation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ you are allowed to translate $S$ so that it is tangent to the light cone $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$. At any point of tangency the restricted metric is indefinite. To do this translation, first translate $S$ so that it is strictly inside the light cone, then let $S$ gently descend until the first moment that it touches the light cone.